# PL/SQL Procedures to create and drop tables

Tags: plsql

I run a procedure to Drop and re-create a table by using PL/SQL but it dosn't work and the table have no update on it .. the script below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure RUBA.pay_backup
    as
       r_create_table varchar(1000);
Begin
    Begin
        r_create_table := 'Drop table payment_backup';
        Execute Immediate r_create_table;

        Exception
        When Others Then
           Null;
    End;

    r_create_table := 'Create Table payment_backup as Select * from payment_table';
    Execute Immediate r_create_table;

End;
/
```

Comment: Looks fine for me. Do you get any error? Did you try to add a commit after you run the procedure?

Comment: Make sure you have your `payment_table` created. Also you should create your `payment_backup` table before executing your code. You code is working fine!

Comment: What is not working? If you are getting any error, post the same.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is that you are dealing with the security model of Oracle that normally requires direct grants vs. via a role when running in the context of a compiled PL/SQL procedure.

You are likely seeing `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`.

Your user probably has `CREATE TABLE` granted via a role, but not directly.
Check this as follows:

```
-- List system privs granted via a role
select * from ROLE_SYS_PRIVS where ROLE in (select ROLE from USER_ROLE_PRIVS)
/
-- List system privs granted directly
select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS
/
```

There are two simple ways to make your procedure work:

**Option 1**

Grant `CREATE TABLE` directly to your user.
Connect as a DBA and do this:

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO RUBA;
```

Unfortunately, this is a bit of a blunt instrument and probably not what you want to do.

**Option 2**

Create your procedure with invoker's rights:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure RUBA.pay_backup AUTHID CURRENT_USER
    as
       r_create_table varchar(1000);
Begin
    Begin
        r_create_table := 'Drop table payment_backup';
        Execute Immediate r_create_table;

        Exception
        When Others Then
           Null;
    End;

    r_create_table := 'Create Table payment_backup as Select * from payment_table';
    Execute Immediate r_create_table;

End;
/
```

Do some experimentation to see how things behave with this version.
Note that you may run into issues if you are running this in a job or when connecting as a different user.

Comment: Your exception routine is erasing any error that may occured, hiding form you the problem. IMHO that structure is one of the worst programming anywhere. In fact Oracle at one time considered making it a compile error, didn't for backward compatibility issues, but does issue a compile warning.

Comment: @Belayer, that was the procedure from the original question, modified only to show the invoker's rights. Why don't you edit this response and put your fix in--I agree with you all the way that exception swallowing is bad news.

Comment: I used `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`, thats what I would have expect anyway... Thanks!